# How can I send plain text email (with line breaks) using sp_send_dbmail?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, emacs, sp-send-dbmail

I have a SQL Server 2008 procedure that sends email via sp_send_dbmail.

I'm using the following code:

```
  set @bodyText = ( select 
                      N'Here is one line of text ' +
                      N'It would be nice to have this on a 2nd line ' +
                      N'Below is some data: ' +
                      N' ' +
                      N' ' +
                      field1 +
                      N' ' +
                      field2 +
                      N' ' +
                      N'This is the last line'
                    from myTable )

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = 'myProfile',
        @recipients = @to,
        @body = @bodyText,
        @body_format = 'TEXT',
        @subject = 'Testing Email' ;
```

My myProfile is set to use the local smtp server, which results in a .EML file in c:\inetpub\mailroot\queue

When I open one of those .eml files (ug - the only thing that can open them is outlook express, looking at them in anything else just shows the body as a base64 encoded blob.) it looks like it's rendering the result as HTML - so I'm not sure if the problem is in the client, or

I've tried putting \n into the message, but that didn't work.  How can I send plain text with line breaks, and verify that the end result looks correct?

BTW, I can't actually send the email to test it with real email clients - corp. network is locked down.

Comment: did any of these answer's solve your problem?

Comment: @KM - yes.  I'm trying to decide which to accept - yours is more elegant, and reads better, but Martins also works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You aren't actually inserting any line breaks. You can embed them directly in a string literal in SQL Server as below.

```
SET @bodyText = (SELECT N'Here is one line of text 
It would be nice to have this on a 2nd line 
Below is some data: 


' + field1 + N' 

' + field2 + N' 

' + N'This is the last line'
                 FROM   myTable);
```

Or a tidier approach might be

```
DECLARE @Template NVARCHAR(max) = 
N'Here is one line of text 
It would be nice to have this on a 2nd line 
Below is some data: 

##field1##

##field2##

This is the last line';

SET @bodyText = (SELECT REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(@Template, 
                       '##field1##', field1), 
                       '##field2##', field2)
                 FROM   myTable);
```

Both will raise an error if `myTable` contains more than one row as you are assigning the result to a scalar variable.

Comment: Surprisingly, it does!  In fact, I can put whole blocks into one pair of quotes.

Comment: really makes the code look funky, I used to do it that way.  however, I found the `CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)` works better with indenting queries and other code.

Comment: Yes it doesn't really work very well with indenting as the `'` needs to go right at the start of the line to avoid injecting a whole load of surplus spaces but it can look a bit more WYSIWYG where that isn't a concern.

Answer (score 22):

I've always used `CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)` to create line breaks (which seems to work mixed in with nvarchar values) in TSQL, so try something like this:

```
DECLARE @CRLF char(2)
       ,@bodyText nvarchar(max)
       ,@field1  nvarchar(10)
       ,@field2  nvarchar(10)
SELECT @CRLF=CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
      ,@field1='your data'
      ,@field2='and more'

set @bodyText =
                N'Here is one line of text ' 
                +@CRLF+ N'It would be nice to have this on a 2nd line ' 
                +@CRLF+ N'Below is some data: ' + N' ' + N' ' + ISNULL(@field1,'') + N' ' + ISNULL(@field2 + N' ' ,'')
                +@CRLF+ N'This is the last line' 


PRINT @bodyText
```

OUTPUT:

```
Here is one line of text 
It would be nice to have this on a 2nd line 
Below is some data:   your data and more 
This is the last line
```

this `CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)` will work with `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`, I send formatted e-mails using that all the time.

Comment: Not if you're sending the email with body as HTML

Answer (score 7):

As [Fernando68](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2181188/fernando68) mentions above, if you're allowed HTML emails, set @body_format = 'HTML', then you can use `<br/>` for line-breaks and make it as fancy as you want using all the tags that you get from HTML like line-breaks, img, strong, and so on...

```
set @bodyText = ( select 
                  '<h1>My Data</h1><p>Here is one line of text<br/>
                   It would be nice to have this on a 2nd line <br/>
                   Below is some data: <br/>'
                   + field1 + '<br/>'
                   + field2 + '<br/>'
                   + 'This is the last line</p>'
                   from myTable )

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'myProfile',
    @recipients = @to,
    @body = @bodyText,
    @body_format = 'HTML',
    @subject = 'Testing Email' ;
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the original question but it maybe the best and simplest solution.  I have used this approach to solve this problem *reliably* in the past (I found a text solution that usually worked but not always!).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the plain text email with `CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)` was getting formatted by Outlook that "helpfully" removes extra line breaks (unless it is unchecked in Outlook Options).

In addition, my list of entries would be dynamic, so I put together the STUFF FOR XML PATH that pulled in a concatenated string and simply added a literal empty string with a new line break and then assigned sp_send_dbmail's @body = @emailBody:

```
DECLARE @emailBody VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @emailBody = CONCAT('files: '
    ,(SELECT STUFF((SELECT
    ' 

' + CONCAT([FileName],'.csv')
    FROM localdb.dbo.tableName
    for xml path(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')))
```